# Как получить иконку, если известно расширение файла?

Tags: java, desktop

У меня есть расширение файла. Надо получить изображение, которое является иконкой для данного расширения в операционной системе пользователя. Как это можно сделать? Файла как такового у нас нет, известно только его расширение.

Comment: Уверен в том, что не существует универсального способа. Для каждой ОС придётся писать свою затычку. Вам для какой ОС?

Comment: вообще java-приложение кросс-платформенное. поэтому если надо писать для каждой ОС по-своему, то придется реализовать несколько способов и выбирать в зависимости от ОС

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не смогу проконсультировать по поводу MacOS (не приходится сталкиваться), но ничего не нагуглилось. Под Линукс придётся писать свой способ для каждой среды рабочего стола.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это невероятно, но я нашёл [нужную Вам фичу](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemIcon-java.io.File-) в Джаве. Под Виндоус работает. Под Макосью сейчас нет возможности проверить, но догадываюсь, что тоже работать будет. Под Линуксом всё плохо :(.

Comment: Интересная фича :) Под Мак таким образом тоже работает. Наверное, раз без самого файла невозможно, то придется создавать пустой temporary file с помощью File.createTempFile("name", ".extension") и потом для него получать иконку?

Comment: Нет, по-другому нелья. Эта фича спрятана глупобо в реализции sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.

Comment: Вот за это я и не люблю Джаву :). Вы можете попробовать обдурить её, создав свой собственный «файл», который на самом деле не будет ничего делать с файловой системой, но будет исправно возвращать своё имя. Я так думаю, getSystemIcon для получения иконки ничего кроме имени из этого объекта File и не требуется.

Comment: Мне тут подсказывают,что файл, передаваемый в конструктор File'у не обязан существовать. Так что Вы можете просто указать там просто любое имя с нужным расширением. Хотя не известно, сработает ли вообще всё это… ведь, как минимум, надо проверить, не папки ли это… Видимо надёжный способ — создание временного файла, да… Поэкспериментируйте! :)

Comment: Всё проверил. Действительно, придется создавать временный файл - по времени выполнения в моем случае не критично, хоть и работа с файловой системой дорогая. В общем, при попытке получить иконку к несуществующему файлу падает java.io.FileNotFoundException при вызове метода getShellFolder(File f) - он вызывается внутри FileSystemView.getSystemIcon(File f).

Answer (score 2):

Ок, я нашёл почти универсальный способ.

В принципе, я мог бы сразу догадаться, что нужная фича есть в Qt ;). Вам [сюда](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfileiconprovider.html) и далее по тексту. Привязка Qt к Джаве [тут](http://qtjambi.sourceforge.net).

Под Windows и MacOS это будет работать 100%. Под Линуксом, как обычно, свои заморочки, но можно надеяться, что как-нибудь сработает :).

Естественно, серьёзный недостаток — придётся таскать за собой Qt. Но тут уж либо так, либо никак ;).

Answer (score 1):

В Windows всё это можно достать из реестра. Простого пути нет, так что придётся немного напрячься.

Вот [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GetFileTypeAndIcon.aspx) описано, что и как делать и есть пример кода на C#. Думаю, перевести его на Java будет не сильно сложно.

Готовое решение на Java найдётся едва ли.